# Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3

Missing Purpose String in `Info.plist` File of `Xcode`, when we upload App to App Store some Privacy `String` has been mandatory yo provide e.g. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` but we have not used these type of service in Our Project so why we provide these Privacy String. When ever we provide some string for that, App Store team reject that build for the reason is "You are not specify accurate Privacy String in Info.plist". So what is the right string if we not using location in our project and then what will be the Privacy string in `Info.plist` if we include these privacy.

We have tried before that, This app uses location when user use this app.[image: This is the mail which is provided by App Store Team]

Answer (score 1):

Do you are using some framework that could be asking for user locations sensitive data? Even if this is not asking for permission when using the app, sometimes just by containing the snippet in the code is already a reason to be necessary to enter the description of the permission.

Also see the capabilities section if some map or locations feature is selected.

I know you said that you are not using location services, but just to keep the conscience clean. Are you usign CoreLocation framework in your code? The CoreLocation framework is attached to you project? Search for "CLLocationManager" in your code, sometimes is common let this unnoticed.

Looks like your are using some framework, lib/pod that are using CoreLocation inside, by the information that you passed on, i suspect that this have some connection.

Comment: Thanks. Did the search and found that one pod use it. It helped.